# Resque-web path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I just upgraded to rails 3.1 and is getting a weird routing problem with resque-web

I've mounted resque-web on my routing.rb like this:

```
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
```

when my server is up going to 0.0.0.0:5000/resque works fine but declaring the path 'resque_path' in my erb.html files gives me

```
undefined local variable or method `resque_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001038e9eb0>:0x000001038a7650>
```

it's even listed on my rake routes as:

```
resque_server        /resque                     {:to=>Resque::Server}
```

'resque_path' should be working!  i hav no idea why it is now.  anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `resque_server_path`? That could do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you check rake routes you can see that solution is:

`resque_web_path`